# javascript injection $http post method does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, cors

so I am creating Google Chrome Extension and at first I was injecting my html, angular and javascripts via content script. No I need to inject it by my own. I made that! But the problem is that when it was injected via content script my login method worked just fine in return I got token (that's what I needed), but when injected by myself my login function does not work anymore and it throws this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.cheapwatcher.com/api/Authenticate. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://anywebsitename.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

This is my login method (I haven't changed anything since changed the injection type):

```
angular.module('app').controller('LoginController', LoginController);

LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$state'];

function LoginController($scope, $http, $location, $state) {
    $scope.login = function (user) {
        user.grant_type = 'password';
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://www.cheapwatcher.com/api/Authenticate',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            transformRequest: function (obj) {
                var str = [];
                for (var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            },
            data: user
        }).success(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            $(".cheap-watcher").fadeOut(1500, function () {                         
                $(".cheap-watcher").fadeIn($state.go("logout"), {}, { location: false }).delay(2000);
            })
        }).error(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });      
    };
};
```

Can I do something without making CORS on server side? Because as I said injecting via content script works just fine

**UPDATE!**

So I changed my login method from $http to $.ajax. Everything is the same just instead of $http I wrote $.ajax and removed headers section. In chrome source control the error is the same, but now in fiddler I can see that my request was successful. How is that possible?

now login method looks like this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('LoginController', LoginController);

LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$state'];

function LoginController($scope, $http, $location, $state) {
    $scope.login = function (user) {
        user.grant_type = 'password';
        return $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.cheapwatcher.com/api/Authenticate",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            method: 'POST',
            transformRequest: function (obj) {
                var str = [];
                for (var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            },
            data: user
        }).success(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            $(".cheap-watcher").fadeOut(1500, function () {
                $(".cheap-watcher").fadeIn($state.go("logout"), {}, { location: false }).delay(2000);
            })
        }).error(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    };
};
```

**UPDATE NR. 2!**

I saw that error is coming from http://anywebsitename.com 's index page. So I assume that my login request is running not from my extension but from website content. Are there any communication possible from injected script to background script?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Requesting cross-origin permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr), you can add `http://www.cheapwatcher.com/api/Authenticate` to `permissions` sections.

> By adding hosts or host match patterns (or both) to the permissions section of the manifest file, the extension can request access to remote servers outside of its origin.

Comment: Would be nice if that were so easy... My permissions section has included both **"http://*/*"** and **"https://*/*"** so it should work. - @haibaraAi

Comment: @NikasŽalias, you'd better put your ajax call in background script, which won't be blocked by Same-origin Policy if you have declared permissions. You can take a look at the official guide [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) for more info about communicating between content scripts and background page

Answer (score 0):

To use CORS within Angular, we need to tell Angular that we’re using CORS. We use the
`.config()` method on our Angular app module to set two options.

1. We need to tell Angular to use the XDomain and
2. We must remove the X-Requested-With header from all of our requests

   ```
   angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function($httpProvider) {
       $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
       delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers
               .common['X-Requested-With'];
   });
   ```

Comment: _XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.cheapwatcher.com/api/Authenticate. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://anywebsitename.com' is therefore not allowed access._ still the same error - @adityasingh

Comment: Does your server allow request from this domain?

Comment: Yes it allows - @AdityaSingh